# Implementing JSON feed on an ASP.NET 2.0 web application with JSON.NET

Tags: asp.net, json.net

I've been tasked with implementing a JSON feed on an asp.net website that will be consumed by 3rd party apps (such as IPhone, Android, etc) and I'd like to follow best practices.

An example of what I'd like to achieve would be something similar to: http://api.entertainment.ie/restaurants/listbycounty.asp

I've chosen the JSON.net api as this seems to be highly recommended.

My Google-fu must be failing me as I can't find a single full example code for an Asp.net web application with JSON.net implemented on it, so I've no real concept of where to begin.

My question is fairly simple:

- Should I create this sort of feed as an ASPX, or ASHX file? Or even a .NET Web Service? (Remember that the tools that will be using this feed are on external apps like IPhones, etc)

I created a test feed in both ASHX and ASPX format ... here is the code (I'm using Subsonic to populate the collection) ... are either of these along the correct lines?

**ASPX:**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Response.ContentType = "application/json"

    Dim objWCounty As New WLocation.wCounty
    Dim objVwCounty As ICollection(Of VwCounty) = objWCounty.GetCountyFromCountryID(Enums.Country.Ireland, True)

    Dim sJSON As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objVwCounty)

    Response.Write(sJSON)

End Sub
```

**ASHX:**

```
Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json"

    Dim objWCounty As New WLocation.wCounty
    Dim objVwCounty As ICollection(Of VwCounty) = objWCounty.GetCountyFromCountryID(Enums.Country.Ireland, True)

    Dim sJSON As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objVwCounty)

    context.Response.Write(sJSON)

End Sub

ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    Get
        Return False
    End Get
End Property
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will most certainly want to use a handler in this situation as it will be much less overhead than an actual .aspx page.

Other than a lack of error handling, your implementation looks good from here.

I have used JSON.Net before (watch out for DateTime formats), but I typically use the built in [.Net JSON serializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170.aspx) in conjuction with WCF now. However, it may not be an option for you if you are constrained to .Net 2.0

### UPDATE:

*I was going to respond about error handling in the comments, but it was getting long. So... here are my thoughts on error handling.*

Error handling can be as simple or sophisticated as you want to make it, but I generally follow a couple of guidelines when dealing with services (which is essentially what you have here).

- **Errors should be part of the published API**

  - A service is a contract, and consumers of that contract need a way to know if something has gone wrong, and handle it accordingly. You should always provide some token or alternate message format that will indicate an error has occurred. An easy example is a list of error codes with specific meanings.
- **Be conscience of your audience when choosing the amount of information to include**

  - You *could* just send down an exception message, and stack trace to the end user, but at best you will probably be including information they don't care about. Worse yet, you may be providing a would be hacker valuable details about the internals of the system he is trying to compromise.
  - In a lot of scenarios it is enough to simply say "Hey there was a problem!", but in other circumstances (like an internal LOB) application, you may need to provide a ticket number or unique token that can be used by support to better troubleshoot the problem.
- **Exceptions should be exceptional!**

  - Make sure you are coding defensively! Never trust user input, and check for every reasonable scenario that *could* possibly prevent the operation from succeeding. If it is possible that data could be missing, then you should check for that and inform the user. Again when working with JSON it is easy enough to create a property that represent some sort of return code.
  - Unhanded exceptions represent true bugs, and should be fixed pronto. In the case of a service like this, you will need to log the exception, swallow it, and let the end user know something really bad happened.

An example JSON package with error codes:

```
{
    data{...},
    error{...}
}
```

In the above case if the error property exists, then you know something went wrong.

There is no one size fits all error handling scheme, but whatever you do be consistent. Having a good error handling plan and following it is more important than what you do. However, having *NO* plan is a sure way to create a lot of headaches for you and your end users.

Comment: Thanks! Always good to be sure you're going down the right track before getting too far into it :) (I hadn't added error handling to the examples just to keep it simple here) .... on the topic of error handling though, what would be the best way to "return" an error via JSON?

Answer (score 0):

If your using SubSonic 2.x it has a built-in RESTHandler that might already do what you need.  The specific file/code for can be found in /SubSonic/HttpHandlers/RESTfullUrl.cs, it can return XML/RSS/JSON.

Here are some examples documented in the source.

```
/// http://domain/service_directory/table_or_view/[key].[format]
/// or with a REST command
/// http://domain/service_directory/table_or_view/[command].[format]?[params]
/// for search, this is
/// http://domain/service_directory/table_or_view/search.[format]?paramname=paramvalue
/// SPs use
/// http://domain/service_directory/spname/exec.[format]?[params]
```

The only problem I had with this, was that the default implementation only supported having a single provider.  I modified the code and [submitted](http://www.zachhunter.com/2010/02/subsonic-2-2-resthandler-add-providername-support/) to the forums to be added.

Comment: thanks, although what I'm really trying to do is create a JSON feed irrespective of the DAL used (so that I can teach others that don't use SubSonic)